# Test method passed but code coverage remains 0%

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

**Original Class:**

```
public class LightningTabs {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account saveAccount(Account acc) {
        insert acc;
        return acc;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account getA(String accountNumber) {
        Account resultValues = [Select Name, Ownership
                                From Account where AccountNumber like : accountNumber];
        return resultValues;     
    }
```

**Test Class:**

```
 @isTest 
    static void saveAccountTest(){
        Account acc = new Account(Name= 'Edureka', Ownership= 'Education', AccountNumber= 'ED736025');
        insert acc;
    }
    @isTest 
    static void getATest(){
        Account acc = new Account(Name= 'Edureka', Ownership= 'Education', AccountNumber= 'ED736025');
        insert acc;
        Account resultValues = [Select Name, Ownership
                                From Account where AccountNumber like : acc.accountNumber];
        String N = acc.AccountNumber;
        System.assertNotEquals('ED736026', N);
    }
}
```

In the original class I have two methods. One is for creating Account and the other fetches Account detail based on a parameter. Now I wrote a Test class which showed that my methods are passing but unfortunately code coverage is 0%. I am unable to understand where I am going wrong.

I even started learning Test class a few minutes back so apologies for any foolish mistake in the code. Kindly help me out and thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Coverage is gained only when that particular piece of code is executed in a test context. Since you aren't calling the code in your `LightningTabs` class, it gains no coverage. You should be explicitly calling `LightningTabs.saveAccount()` and `LightningTabs.getA()`. I'd recommend taking a look through the questions tagged as [tag:canonical-qa]. The common testing problems/advice is contained there.

Comment: Thanks for the help.